# What does "no aircraft change" mean?

Tags: air-travel, transit, qatar-airways

While buying a ticket, I checked the airlines and it is exactly like this photo. Does it mean we just stay inside the plane for 1 hour and half and then leave or ...? It writes 'no aircraft change'.

It is important since I need to know whether I need to have a transit visa or not and in case we do not exit the airplane I think we do not need it. Otherwise, I am sure due to nationality we need to. On the other hand. 1 hour and half of course is not enough for transit or so. This is why I doubt.

[image]

Comment: Have you asked the the airline (Qatar) if passengers are required to leave the aircraft during the stop?

Comment: Actually not yet.

Comment: This can vary a lot. In some cases you don’t leave the aircraft, in others you will be able to stretch your legs in the gate area, in others still you can actually go through the whole transit/departures area. Depends a lot on the airport layout, whether they take passengers at that airport, and more. Unless someone around here has taken the same route it will be difficult to answer.

Comment: In general for Australia you will need to exit the aircraft and re-clear security for a tag flight like this, however I can't speak for this specific flight.

Comment: I've had this happen to me before and they let me stay on the plane while they prepped it for the next flight.  But that was a domestic flight entirely within the US.  I imagine the rules are different for international flights.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An Australian transit visa is required unless you are Australian or New Zealander or [your nationality is exempt for an eligible flight](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/transit-771/travellers-eligible-to-transit-without-visa).

This is a fifth freedom flight with passenger operations in Adelaide. While you might be able to stay on the aircraft during the stop and not pass immigration, embarking and disembarking passengers means that it is considered a flight to Australia and everyone is subject to Australian rules. Australian authorities implement an advanced passenger information system that includes electronic visa verification; without a valid visa you will be refused boarding for any flight to Australia.

Comment: Yes yes I applied for transit visa. I just want to be sure that layover is enough.

Comment: Guys this is the answer from Qatar: Yes, the minimum connection time in Doha is 45 minutes, and for the stopover in Adelaide, aircraft will not change, but there might be screening. However, you can only check in from the first point of departure with the check-in counter staff. –

Comment: My final question is, is 1 hour layover enough really in Doha to change the flight? The qatarairways itself offers it. I mean in case airplane offers an option it considers all of these right?

Comment: The flight doesn't connect through Australia. The itinerary shows AKL (Auckland, NZ), not ADL (Adelaide).

Comment: @dbkk It says "Stop (ADL)". Few aircrafts can fly directly from Doha to NZ and it is likely not a profitable route without fifth freedom passengers.

Comment: QR914 is marketed for DOH-ADL, ADL-AKL and DOH-(ADL)-AKL.

Answer (score 9):

Even if you wouldn't need a visa if you decide to stay on the plane, there is always the risk that they change the airplane on short notice, for mechanical reasons or whatever. If you then need a visa to get out of the one plane and into another, you could be in deep trouble. It is not the airline's problem, but yours.

So make sure you have what you need to enter the terminal.

Comment: Yes, exactly this. Schedule changes - with either long or short notice - should always be assumed as a possibility. Although, it is actually sort of the airline's problem, too: If you're denied entry, they're generally required to transport you back to your point of origin. And, due to that requirement, they'll usually just deny you boarding in the first place if they think you might be refused entry.

Comment: Ok great. So with transit visa the layover is not an issue right? I mean short layover is ok even if they want to change the flight they are responsible for the time right? I mean if they want to change the flight they will add some more hours right?

Comment: @Aganju Guys this is the answer from Qatar: Yes, the minimum connection time in Doha is 45 minutes, and for the stopover in Adelaide, aircraft will not change, but there might be screening. However, you can only check in from the first point of departure with the check-in counter staff. –

Comment: My final question is, is 1 hour layover enough really in Doha to change the flight? The qatarairways itself offers it. I mean in case airplane offers an option it considers all of these issues right?

Comment: Yes, it's enough; and anyway _this is_ the airline's problem. No worries there.